# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline update the runtime stack of existing app service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been trying to automate updating the runtime version of already existing Azure App Services. Currently I have around 20 running App Services (Windows), each on the same runtime stack (let's say .NET 5). I would like to manage versions and upgrade to .NET 6 (and later to .NET 7 etc.) with minimum manual work required. The current flow of the process looks like that:

1. Code is being merged with master in Pull Request;
2. *Build Pipeline* is triggered, runs project with tests, publishes artifact with the newest build (I've already updated it to use .NET 6, my project is configured for .NET 6 as well).
3. *Release Pipeline* is triggered, because new Artifact is published;
4. This pipeline has 20 stages, one for each app service - it deploys the code artifact using *Azure App Service deploy* task.

I would like to update all these app services without me going into azure portal -> app service configuration and changing the runtime manually. I don't really know what is the best place to put "something" that updates the runtime automatically/after changing some single parameter by myself to indicate that it should now update all these App Services to .NET 6.

What I've considered:

1. Run some inline azure cli script at the beginning of Release Pipeline (I believe there is an agent task for it) that updates the runtime stack of each app service to desired version - but I haven't found a way to achieve it via Azure Cli (the azure cli equivalent of going to azure portal -> app service config -> changing runtime). Did I miss something? Is it the right approach?
2. Make some Powershell Script that gets invoked *somewhere in the flow* that bumps runtime to desired version provided in parameter;
3. I've considered that there possibly is some nicer way to control the runtime version of already running App Services, but I cannot find any.

Could you guys guide me towards the correct approach? Thanks in advance, if any additional info is required I will, of course, provide it.